# Display Widget in phtml file magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product, magento2.3, widgets

I have Following widget and its working in cms page but now I want it to display  in **phtml file**

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed" uiComponent="widget_recently_viewed" page_size="10" show_attributes="name,image,price,learn_more" show_buttons="add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist" template="product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml" type_name="Recently Viewed Products"}}
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107750/magento-2-call-a-widget-in-phtml-file Try this @HarshJayswal

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran have already tried but it shows an error if you know how to set my widget according to that answer than please post the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try with below way.

```
$recViewBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed::class);
$recViewBlock->setTitle("Recently Viewed Products");
$recViewBlock->setProductsCount(10);
$recViewBlock->setTemplate("product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml");
$recViewBlock->setDisplayType("recently.view.products");
$recViewBlock->setShowAttribute(add_to_cart,add_to_compare,add_to_wishlist);

echo $recViewBlock->toHtml();
```

**Note :** Above code is not tested you have to check. [For more detail click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166218/how-to-call-widget-with-products-of-specific-category-in-phtml-file)

I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer but is shows error

Answer (score 0):

**phtml file :-**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed")->setDisplayType("widget_recently_viewed")->setProductsCount("5")->setTemplate("product/widget/viewed/grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, This is not working in 2.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Widget\RecentlyViewed")->setDisplayType("your_display_type")->toHtml();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have such type of string

```
$widget = '{{widget type="Magento\Cms\Block\Widget\Block" template="widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="100"}}';
```

you can show widget content without createBlock etc.

You need to add \Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter to your block or create it via Object Manager in phtml.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var $filter \Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter */
$filter = $objectManager>create(\Magento\Widget\Model\Template\Filter::class);
```

Than you can show your widget like this

```
<?= html_entity_decode($filter->filter($widget)) ?>
```

Works even if $widget contains other html tags, they will also be shown.